# Changing the subject of a formula involving the floor.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove if $3\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is onto. But I cannot seem to be able to change the subject of my formula to $x$ from $y=3\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor$. I don't understand how I'm supposed to make $x$ the subject in this case involving the floor of a number.

Comment: Domain and codomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the function is onto or not depends highly on the codomain, but I will assume the function is from the integers to the integers. If this is the case then the function is certainly not onto. Consider $y=1$. There is no $x$ such that $3\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor=1$ because $\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is an integer, so $3\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is a multiple of $3$, but $1$ is not a multiple of $3$.

You don't need to invert the function to test whether it is onto or not - all you have to do is check whether for every $y$ in the codomain there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: I think it more likely that the intended domain is $\Bbb R$; at any rate I’d definitely point out that your argument applies for any reasonable choice of domain.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. And the intended domain is an integer not a real number. Thanks for your help.